# swaping of two elements in a pythonic list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to swap two elements in a list, but maybe I'm doing it wrong! It doesn't swap elements.

```
f= [4,3,1,2]
f[0],f[f.index(min(f[2:]))] = f[f.index(min(f[2:]))] ,f[0]

print(f)
[4, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: `idx = f[2:].index(min(f[2:])) + 2
f[0], f[idx] = f[idx], f[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ind = f[2:].index(min(f[2:])) + 2
f[ind], f[0] = f[0], f[ind]
```

However, this code seems quite uneffective as you have, at worst, to parse `f` two times (one to find the minimum and one to find its `index`, so I would recommand doing this with a `for` loop, or using `numpy.argmin` if you already use `numpy` in your project.

```
ind = 2
minim = f[2]
for i,t in enumerate(f[3:]):
    if t < minim:
        ind = i + 3
        minim = t

f[0], f[ind] = minim, f[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1cpy = f[f.index(min(f[2:]))]
f[f.index(min(f[2:]))] = f[0]
f[0] = var1cpy
```

It worked for me